# Win-Loss Record in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, trigger, view

I'm building a database on Microsoft SQL Server to teach myself SQL. I am a big UFC fan so I'd like to build a database on UFC fighters.

I'm building two tables `fight` and `fighter`. The `fighter` table will have stats like weight, height, birthday, etc. as well as a column for wins, losses, draws, and NC (no contest). The `fight` table will have a winner_id column and a loser_id column as well as is_draw and is_nc columns.

How can I best create a link between the winner_id/loser_id columns from the `fight` table to the wins and losses columns for the `fighter` table?

There is one caveat. Usually MMA fighters will come to the UFC with experience in other organizations. So they will already have a record of wins and losses prior to the UFC. My database will only record UFC fights. So I can't have those previous wins and losses in the [fight] table. For that reason, I've decided to use triggers for now.

**Question:** is there a better way to do this other than triggers? I'm thinking setting the wins column = a base number + the number of times their fighter_id is listed in the winner_id column. But how would I do that? Would I need to use a view?

Here is the trigger I have created.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_fight_ResultUpdateFighter
ON fight
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Win
    DECLARE @winner_id int
    DECLARE @loser_id int
    DECLARE @is_draw bit
    DECLARE @is_nc bit
    SELECT 
        @winner_id = winner_id,
        @loser_id = loser_id,
        @is_draw = is_draw,
        @is_nc = is_nc
        FROM inserted

    --Wins
    UPDATE fighter
    SET wins = wins+1
    WHERE fighter_id = @winner_id

    --Loss
    UPDATE fighter
    SET losses = losses+1
    WHERE fighter_id = @loser_id

    --Draw
    UPDATE fighter
    SET draws = draws + 
        CASE
            WHEN @is_draw = 1
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    WHERE fighter_id = @winner_id
    AND fighter_id = @loser_id

    --NC
    UPDATE fighter
    SET nc = nc + 
        CASE
            WHEN @is_nc = 1
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    WHERE fighter_id = @winner_id
    AND fighter_id = @loser_id

END
```

Comment: Take care with triggers, `inserted` or `deleted` can have more than one row.

Comment: As @mcNets states: [`inserted` and `deleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) are virtual **tables**. These tables can have more than one row in them. You are using these tables as though they only have one row. That is an error.

Comment: The cleanest way to deal with the win loss for any particular fighter is to create a view using COUNT and GROUP BY.  The calculation will always be correct and you don't have to deal with a whole other set of headaches that go with triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by determining the stats at run-time. Only if that turns out to be too expensive, I would denormalize the statistics:

```
select f1.fighter_id
     , count(case when f2.is_draw = 0 and f1.fighter_id = f2.winnner_id then 1 end) as #wins
     , count(case when f2.is_draw = 0 and f1.fighter_id = f2.looser_id then 1 end) as #loss
     , count(case when f2.is_draw = 1 and f1.fighter_id in (f2.winner_id, f2.looser_id) then 1 end) as #draws
     , ...   
from fighter f1
join fights  f2
    on f1.fighter_id in (f2.winnner_id, f2.looser_id)
group by f1.fighter_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger there are some errors:

**The first: Calculation of draws**

You have write this:

```
--Draw
UPDATE fighter
SET draws = draws + 
    CASE
        WHEN @is_draw = 1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
WHERE fighter_id = @winner_id
AND fighter_id = @loser_id
```

But this query can't update anything because `@winner_id` and `@loser_id` are always different. You must change `AND` with `OR`

**The second: Calculation of nc**

the same error in draws repeated here, the solution is the same

**The third: Are you sure your trigger process only one row?**

In `INSERTED` table you have all rows involved in a INSERT or UPDATE statement.

If you have only a statement as follow:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (field list) VALUES (list of values)
```

You have involved only one row and your trigger it's OK but, if you have a query as follow:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
SELECT * FROM anothertable
WHERE conditions
```

If `SELECT * FROM` returns more than one row, your trigger works fine only for the first of those rows.

In this case you must deeply change your trigger code, a possible solution in this case is use an `UPDATE ... FROM` operation

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to trigger, for anything but a check, use caution. Some things in life are "wrong way go back" and triggers are definitively one of them!
Since what you need is a calculated column, I would say best go with a "View". As you've said:

> wins column = a base number + the number of times their fighter_id is listed in the winner_id column

View are more flexible, easier to spot and easier to maintain. Also, the trigger should insert a record twice per game: one for the loser and one for the winner. Too much work. A view like the one below could do better:

The code would look like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT (winner_id),  winner_id AS Fighter,  'win' as ResType 
 FROM Results 
 WHERE is_draw = 0 
 GROUP BY winner_id 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT COUNT (*),  loser_id as Fighter 'loss' as ResType 
 FROM Results 
 WHERE is_draw = 0 
 GROUP BY loser_id 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT SUM(CAST is_draw as INT)  winner_id,  "draw" as res_type 
 FROM results 
 GROUP BY winner_id
```

Now you have all the wins, loses grouped by the fighter_id.